# Webpack preprocess functions with parameters like DefinePlugin

Tags: webpack, webpack-plugin

I have been using Webpack's DefinePlugin.runtimeValue to inject calculated settings into my app.

**webpack.config.js**

```js
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    COMPUTED_CONSTANT: webpack.DefinePlugin.runtimeValue(
        function () { return JSON.stringify(countPuppies()) }, []
    )
})
```

**app.js**

```js
const total = COMPUTED_CONSTANT
```

What I would really like to do however is process a function with *parameters* as well. ie:

**app.js**

```js
var someValue = 7;

var total = COMPILE_TIME_GLOBAL_FUNC(someValue) // = 14
// Compiles to: var total = 14
```

Is there any way of accomplishing this or something similar (at compile time) in webpack?